# Can i convert a string in format Mddyyy to datetime object c# core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I trying to parse a string like 4212021 where 4 is the month, 21 is the day, and 2021 is the year, into a DateTime object. I've tried using the following code but for some reason I am getting 'String '4212021' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.':

```
string datetimestring = "4122021";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(datetimestring, "Mddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You will need some kind of delimiter in the date string… 1212020… is that January 21st or December 1st?

Comment: there is not enough information on how your string will come to provide a robust answer for you.  Are days always 2 digits or is 422021 to represent the second of April.   Provide a bit more background to get a better solution.

Comment: @JohnG day format is `dd`, so for your example is 2020-01-21. It would be a problem is day format was `d`

Comment: I should have made it more clear in the question that all the input will be according to the sample provided in the question.  @Sorceri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work without date separators. So you could add them:

```
string format = "Mddyyyy";
CultureInfo culture =  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string separator = culture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator;
if(datetimestring.Length >= format.Length)
{
    int firstIndex = datetimestring.Length % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1;
    datetimestring = datetimestring.Insert(firstIndex, separator);
    datetimestring = datetimestring.Insert(firstIndex + 2 + separator.Length, separator);
}
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(datetimestring, culture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

This works also if the month has two digits like in `"12122021"`.

Another, maybe simpler way was to use `ParseExact` with `"Mddyyyy HHmmss"` and append zero time:

```
datetimestring = datetimestring + " 000000"; // check first length ofc
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(datetimestring, "Mddyyyy HHmmss", culture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just the "M" modificator that does not work if you use it without separators AND with variable length. If you ensure leading zeros, it should work. ("04" instead of "4")

```
    string datetimestring = 4122021.ToString("D8");
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(datetimestring, "Mddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Comment: The value starts off as a string, so the first line should have `int.Parse("4122021").ToString("D8")` as the value.

Comment: My bet was, that the original value is an integer and was converted to string before to make it work with `ParseExcact()` - but you're right - that was not the question. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since your day is always 2 digits (`dd`) you can just append a `0` to the start of the string when the month only has 1 digit, and use the `MM` for month:

```
string datetimestring = "4122021";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(datetimestring.PadLeft(8,'0'), "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am imagining you have a special reason for not changing the input. You can try this way, it will work.

```html
string datetimestring = "4122021";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(datetimestring.Length < 8 ? $"0{datetimestring}" : datetimestring, "Mddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

See if it is appropriate for your context?